# How to apply and configure gradle plugin in external build file

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I tried to split the `build.gradle` file into several smaller ones to reduce the size and to encapsulate different functionalities. I ended up with:

```
// build.gradle
plugins {
  id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm" version "1.2.30"
}

apply from: 'klint.gradle'
```

and

```
// klint.gradle
buildscript {
  repositories {
   maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath "gradle.plugin.org.jlleitschuh.gradle:ktlint-gradle:3.1.0"
  }
}


//apply plugin: "org.jlleitschuh.gradle.ktlint"
apply plugin: org.jlleitschuh.gradle.ktlint.KtlintPlugin

ktlint {
    verbose = true
    reporter = ReporterType.JSON
}
```

But when running `./gradlew ktlintCheck` I get:

```
* Where:
Script '...klint.gradle' line: 14

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating script.
> Could not find method klint() for arguments [klint_bg1dwp9kv02sa992h3mtpaomq$_run_closure1@1c656f64] on root project 'proj' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
```

I assume that the plugin is applied (because no error happened there) but the configuration doesn't work. How can the plugin be applied and configured in the external-script?

Comment: Hi, did you find an answer for this?

Comment: Hi, to be honest, I cannot remember and not work in that company anymore. sry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `buildscript` block is evaluated at the beginning and determines which plugins and tasks are available for use in the rest of the build script.

For my experience what you are trying to do (the `buildscript` block into an `apply` script) isn’t supported.

Comment: Hm, I see. That's unfortunate. Do you think it is possible then to just apply another plugin and configure it in the external script? So do the `buildscript` step in the main script and the `apply plugin: ...klint` and the `kling { ... }` in the external script?

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience, you should have a copy of the buildscript code block in both base build.gradle file and your external build file.

I don't like the design like this, but that's the only way to achieve our goal currently. You can have a try.

Answer (score -1):

If you do not have a `settings.gradle` file create one and add the following line

```
include 'klint'
```

Comment: Nope. This doesn't help. In fact I would have been surprised if tha would have worked, because the `include` is for `adding the given projects to the build`, according to the documentation